# Issue using nested kendo-tabstrip

Tags: kendo-tabstrip

Hello I am using kendo ui , I have one jsp page with tabstrip one of its tab is other jsp file that contains more tabs.. But it is giving me error 
*

> **NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'kendo-surface'. A type with
>   that name is already registered. in BidsScreenUpdated.jsp**

*

Comment: Have you tried appending a guid or some unique value to your tabstrip id?